# Redirecting from Spring Boot server to React client with JWT after performing Google Authorisation with OAuth 2.0

Tags: reactjs, redirect, oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I have a Spring Boot server which performs the entire OAuth 2.0 Authorisation flow by using Google as an auth provider. I use the Spring OAuth library which already has filters for OAuth endpoints for providers like Google and Facebook.

I have a React front end which kicks this flow off by opening a new window with a URL that points to the Google authorisation endpoint on my server when a user clicks login.

When the server has successfully authenticated a user and retrieved a JWT token from Google, I need to pass this back to my React front end and store the token so that the user can then use it to make authorised requests to my backend API.

As far as I understand I cannot get my front end to send a GET request to my backend for the token as the OAuth Authorisation flow works using redirects. Otherwise I could have returned the JWT to my front end in the body of a HTTP response as described here: https://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-bearer.html#ExAccTokResp

My alternative then is to redirect to a front end 'login success' page from the server on a successful authorisation attempt by appending the JWT token as a URL parameter which my front end will then parse and store. Exposing the JWT as a URL parameter doesn't seem safe however, is there a better/more secure way I can redirect back to my client with a JWT token from my server?

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67508811/in-mern-how-do-i-manage-jwt-cookies-client-side/67512267?noredirect=1#comment119335033_67512267

Comment: @Luke, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit confusing why you are fetching the authorization credentials on the resource server. If your intention was to secure you API using google's access tokens, they need to be granted to the client. You are opening yourself up to security issues if you create some bespoke solution for what OAuth already solves.

You have two options really.

1. Set up your backend as an OAuth authorization server and go through an an authorization code grant with PKCE to your frontend. Either map the claims received from google into your own token or include the token as a claim.
2. Complete the google authorization flow in your frontend client using the authorization code with PKCE grant.

The second approach is far better in my opinion. Here is [google's authorization code with PKCE documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app). Disregard their recommendation for javascript apps as [current oauth security best practice](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics#section-2.1.2) recommends against implicit flow.

Comment: Why would I use the authorisation flow with PKCE from my front end when I have a spring boot back end that can keep a secret?

Comment: Does your API share an origin with your frontend?

Comment: @Django Because you are trying to authenticate your application, not your API is the most succinct way to put it.

Comment: I take your point, but from what I've read, if you have a back-end, then authorising through the back end is the most secure way to get an access token. I don't think it makes much difference whether the user authorises through the front end or back end, it does make a difference however when performing the authorisation flow through the front end which is less secure when compared to the back end. I'm still not convinced my current approach is not the right one, I'm just not sure about the best way to send the JWT back to my front end after the user has been authorised.

Comment: @Django "I'm just not sure about the best way to send the JWT back to my front end after the user has been authorised" That's what I'm telling you, OAuth is the right way to do that.

Comment: @Django PKCE is just as secure as client secrets. And if the credentials don't end up where they need to then you've done all this for nothing... Using your backend to complete the code flow is fine if they share an origin as they can safely and securely pass it to the frontend. When they don't, OAuth is exactly what you should be using to grant credentials to the frontend.

Comment: "Using your backend to complete the code flow is fine if they share an origin as they can safely and securely pass it to the frontend."  -> can you expand on this? How so?

Comment: "OAuth is the right way to do that." -> I'm not sure what you mean by this seeing as though both your approach and my approach come under the umbrella of OAuth, I'm just performing the authorisation flow on my server instead of on my client.

Comment: @Django Scenario 1 in my answer. As for the case where they share an origin, your backend could serve a page that just places the tokens in local or session storage then redirects to your react app.

Answer (score -1):

If exposing JWT in url isn't safe, carrying jwt in request header isn't safer either. So as long as not storing anything secret in the jwt, your are safe. To prevent the token from failing into wrong hand, you can set a short expire time, and refresh the jwt periodically. Anyway, the front end is transparent to the user, so don't worry about people seeing it.